# Pass method name to invoke to handler

Tags: c#, reflection, handler

I'm trying to pass via the querysting, the method name to be invoked and have `ProcessRequest` invoke that method in my handler.  I'm learning as I go here, so what would be the best way to do this. Here is what I have...

I get the error `The best overloaded method match for Invoke(object, object[]) has some invalid arguments` on methodInfo.Invoke.

```
 public class SocialSharingHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string method = (string)context.Request.QueryString["m"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(SocialSharingHandler).GetMethod(method);
            methodInfo.Invoke(new SocialSharingHandler(), context.Request.Form);
        }
    }
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
methodInfo.Invoke(new SocialSharingHandler(), new object[] { context.Request.Form });
```

Comment: thank you that seemed to resolve the issue, it will compile but I'm not at a point to see if runs yet. Thanks vc!

Answer (score 0):

The Error Message states the param types expected object and array of object object[]

```
public class SocialSharingHandler : IHttpHandler 
 {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
         string method = (string)context.Request.QueryString["m"];
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
         {
              MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(SocialSharingHandler).GetMethod(method);
              methodInfo.Invoke(new SocialSharingHandler(), new object[] { context.Request.Form });
         }     
     } 
 }
```